# how to use a .sql file as database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

So I recently got an old ASP.NET Web-App from my boss to look into, as I'll be using it for a small project in the future.

The developer of this App defined the following connection-string in the web config:
`Server=localhost; Database=mbw.sql; Uid=admin; Pwd=pass`

I also got the **mbw.sql** file, but cant seem to figure out what to do with it. I was thinking of adding it as a datasource in Visual Studio, but it doesn't seem to be a valid file for that.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I seem to be unable to word my search term correctly for google to give me an answer.

Comment: Which DBMS being used? SQL file just contain SQL query scripts, not an actual DB file. If the query contains database creation, execute it in SQL query tool you have (SSMS, PMA, etc).

Comment: it maybe that the whole db has been exported into a file called .sql - mysql can do dumps and it works very well to import, but like with everything each db variant has its own quirks so you need to know where it came from

Comment: What is in the .sql file? If you open it with a texteditor you can simply read it.

Comment: its basically some sql commands to create a table and insert data into it, most likely auto generated as it has 1500+ lines. I am downloading SSMS right now to try and execute it

Comment: I found that `Server=localhost` is part of MySQL connection string (https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/). You can use MySQL console or other MySQL query tool to execute it (note that MySQL has ability to dump database table into a single SQL file).

Comment: it seems like running the sql script is not possible in the community edition of mysql worbench and I unfortunately only have access to this version

Comment: You are talking about SSMS (which belongs with SQLServer) and MySQL Workbench, which is intended for MySQL (which is a different RDBMS). Does the script give any clues as to what the original RDBMS was?

Comment: > "...it seems like running the sql script is not possible in the community edition..."


That means you got some errors, right? They should give you some clues.

Comment: in the mysql work bench community edition the option to run the script is greyed out, I was able to run it in smss though and it returned a whole lot of errors, mostly syntax and out of range exceptions. I created a sqllocaldb to run the script on first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe they named the database "mbw.sql" and imported the file into that.  The first thing I would look at is what driver is being used and from there load the file into that database.

People do sometimes name things in misleading ways.  You cannot use an SQL file as a database.  This has to be loaded into an RDBMS.  So somebody has done something very odd here in naming things.

One of the two hard questions in computer science.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a tip how i can load the file into a recently created DB? It was created in the CLI by the command sqllocaldb create ""